# Error message "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (DataTable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the simple DataTable that should be populated with data using the bellow AJAX call. Except that when the page load, I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

My Imports

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.semanticui.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

The reason why I have so many imports is because I am working with a very complex datatable.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var contractUrl = "Service.asmx/GetContracts";
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#contracts').DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    stateSave: true,
    lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [
            'pageLength','excel'
        ],
    scrollY:        300,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { width: 200, targets: 0 }
    ],
    fixedColumns: true,
        stateSave: true,
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        type: "POST",
        url: contractUrl,
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        },
    "columns": [ 
            { "data": "Code" }, 
            { "data": "ContractType" }],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "searching": false
} );

table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );
});

</script>
```

Here is my Json

```
[{"Code":"Dev","ContractType":"GPO"}]
```

Comment: which line of your code generate the error?

Comment: did you include the DataTable library in your page ?

Comment: Yes @Hacketo, I will update my question to show how I included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only syntax error you have is defining the `stateSave` property twice on the config object.

I tried to initialize with your code + some dummy data i got from their examples.

I had to comment out `ajax` and `columns` properties. Also, I had to comment `stateSave` (both times :) ), but this might have to do with StackOverflow limitations. To be clear: having it once might not be possible on SO. Having it twice is an error and won't work anywhere.

Everything else seems fine, including the `table.buttons()`.

Because of the duplicated property on config object `DataTable()` does not correctly initiate and the methods you're trying to access are not exposed.

See it working in this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#contracts').DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    // stateSave: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: [
      'pageLength', 'excel'
    ],
    scrollY: 300,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      width: 200,
      targets: 0
    }],
    fixedColumns: true,
    // stateSave: true,
    processing: false,
    // serverSide: true,
    /* "ajax": {
        type: "POST",
        url: contractUrl,
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        },
    // replaced with data, below
        */
    data: dataSet(),
    columns: [
      { title: "Name"},
      { title: "Position"},
      { title: "Office"},
      { title: "Extn."},
      { title: "Start date"},
      { title: "Salary"}
    ],
    lengthMenu: [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    searching: false
  });
  table.buttons().container().appendTo($('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()));
});

function dataSet(){return [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
  ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
  ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
  ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
  ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
  ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
  ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
  ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
  ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
  ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
  ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
  ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
  ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
  ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
  ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
  ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
  ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
  ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
  ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
  ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
  ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
  ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
  ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
  ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
  ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.semanticui.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

<table id="contracts"></table>
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, doing what you suggested changes the error msg to "Uncaught TypeError: this.replace is not a function"